# Getting url from 2 groups of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to find an url based on two groups of radio buttons, my html look like these:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label><input type="radio" name="comp" id="pink" value="Pink">Pink</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="comp" id="black" value="Black">Black</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="skin" id="fair" value="Fair">Fair</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="skin" id="medium" value="Medium">Medium</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="skin" id="tan" value="Tan">Tan</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="skin" id="dark" value="Dark">Dark</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<a href="url from script">CONTINUE</a>
```

I know that I here have to use javascript in order to get the correct url.

I imagine that it must be built somewhat like this:

```
if comp = "pink" then
  switch(skin)
  {
    case Fair:
      url = www.pinkfair.com;
      break;
    case Medium:
      url = www.pinkmedium.com;
      break;
    case Tan:
      url = www.pinktan.com;
      break;
    case Dark:
      url = www.pinkdark.com;
      break;
    }
else
  switch(skin)
  {
    case Fair:
      url = www.blackfair.com;
      break;
    case Medium:
      url = www.blackmedium.com;
      break;
    case Tan:
      url = www.blacktan.com;
      break;
    case Dark:
      url = www.blackdark.com;
      break;
    }
```

But as you can see i'm at bit of a javascript novice, is there anyone who can help me fine-tune the code.

Thanks in advance.

/Jean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have to fetch the url based on the selected radio buttons from two radio button groups, the logic that you have written will actually work perfectly fine. I have written the same in JavaScript/JQuery as you can see below.

But before that I want to show you the simple solution by adding the url attributes to the radio buttons, which will reduce code a little bit.

Here is the working (tested) solution.

Html

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label><input type="radio" name="comp" id="pink" value="Pink">Pink</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="comp" id="black" value="Black">Black</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="skin" id="fair" value="Fair" data-pinkurl="www.pinkfair.com" data-blackurl="www.blackfair.com" >Fair</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="skin" id="medium" value="Medium" data-pinkurl="www.pinkmedium.com" data-blackurl="www.blackmedium.com">Medium</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="skin" id="tan" value="Tan" data-pinkurl="www.pinktan.com" data-blackurl="www.blacktan.com">Tan</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="skin" id="dark" value="Dark" data-pinkurl="www.pinkdark.com" data-blackurl="www.blackdark.com">Dark</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Script

```
var comp = $("input[type='radio'][name='comp']:checked").val();
var url = '';

if (comp == "Pink"){
   url = $("input[type='radio'][name='skin']:checked").attr("data-pinkurl");
}
else{
   url = $("input[type='radio'][name='skin']:checked").attr("data-blackurl");
}
```

Also, as mentioned above, below is your updated code, which works fine as well.

```
var comp = $("input[type='radio'][name='comp']:checked").val();
var skin = $("input[type='radio'][name='skin']:checked").val();
var url = '';

if (comp == "Pink"){
  switch(skin)
  {
    case "Fair":
      url = "www.pinkfair.com";
      break;
    case "Medium":
      url = "www.pinkmedium.com";
      break;
    case "Tan":
      url = "www.pinktan.com";
      break;
    case "Dark":
      url = "www.pinkdark.com";
      break;
    }
}
else{
  switch(skin)
  {
    case "Fair":
      url = "www.blackfair.com";
      break;
    case "Medium":
      url = "www.blackmedium.com";
      break;
    case "Tan":
      url = "www.blacktan.com";
      break;
    case "Dark":
      url = "www.blackdark.com";
      break;
    }
}
```

Finally, if you don't want to use jQuery and want a pure JavaScript based solution then you need to check each radio button and see if it has been selected.

```
if (document.getElementById('pink').checked) {
  comp = document.getElementById('pink').value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, switch it looks like I need, I'm not locked to a particular structure of my URLs. But how do I get url variable into my link? I have tried to put the following into the script, but it does not work:

    document.write('<a href="http://' + url + '">CONTINUE</a>');

Thank you for your great help.

/ Jean

Comment: I have tried this and it works perfectly.
`var url = 'sajad.wordpress.com';
document.write('<a href="http://' + url + '">CONTINUE</a>');`

Comment: Also, please _accept_ this answer, if it has solved your problem.

Comment: I still can not get it to work. I have checked and I think that it is related to that I write it in an XHTML document. Is there any alternative to document.write works with xhtml? /ean

Comment: try this: `document.body.appendChild('<a href="http://' + url + '">CONTINUE</a>');`

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be adding specific classes to radio buttons like this (you can also use selectors by name, I personally find selecting classes easier):

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label><input class="first" type="radio" name="comp" id="pink" value="Pink">Pink</label>
    <label><input class="first" type="radio" name="comp" id="black" value="Black">Black</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label><input class="second" type="radio" name="skin" id="fair" value="Fair">Fair</label>
    <label><input class="second" type="radio" name="skin" id="medium" value="Medium">Medium</label>
    <label><input class="second" type="radio" name="skin" id="tan" value="Tan">Tan</label>
    <label><input class="second" type="radio" name="skin" id="dark" value="Dark">Dark</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<a class="resultLink" href="url from script">CONTINUE</a>
```

...and since you already keep parts of output url as values/ids, have jQuery handle the rest...

```
$('.first, .second').change(function() {
    var firstPart = $('.first:checked').val();
    var secondPart = $('.second:checked').val();
    var url = 'www.' + firstPart + secondPart + '.com';

    $('.resultLink').attr('href', url);
})
```

For more complex scenario, use solution provided by Sajad Deyargaroo.

Comment: Should be `$('.first, .second')`, otherwise you only match things that are `.first` AND `.second`, i.e. nothing.

Comment: In actual scenario the url will obviously not be concatenation of values from two radio buttons, so in the above approach we still have to write ifs and switchs.